# Verbesserung in Prozent als Bereich für mehrere Fälle angeben

Tags: style, idiomaticity

Ich möchte ausdrücken, dass eine Methode in der Lage ist in fünf betrachteten Fällen ein besseres Ergebnis zu liefern, welches in einem Bereich zwischen 1 % und 14 % liegt (also z.B. 1 %, 4 %, 6 %, 10 %, 14 %).

Mir schwirren einige Varianten im Kopf herum:

> Mit seiner Methode können die Ergebnisse für alle fünf Fälle von 1 % bis 14 % verbessert werden.

> Mit seiner Methode können die Ergebnisse für alle fünf Fälle zwischen 1 % und 14 % verbessert werden.

> Mit seiner Methode können die Ergebnisse für alle fünf Fälle im Bereich von 1 % bis 14 % verbessert werden.

Welche der Varianten ist am gängisten?

Comment: Was ist gemeint: Es wurden überhaupt nur 5 Fälle ("in allen 5 Fällen") betrachtet, und bei denen sind Verbesserungen zwischen 1 und 14% möglich? Oder es wurden z.B. 100 Fälle betrachtet, und bei denen, die im Wertebereich zwischen 1 und 14% liegen, sind noch Verbesserungen möglich? Oder es wurden 100 Fälle betrachtet, und aus denen wurden schon 5 eigens genannt und besonders hervorgehoben, und bei genau diesen 5 sind Verbesserungen möglich, die zwischen 1 und 14% liegen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wenn zwei Zahlen angegeben werden, ist es nicht nötig "von X bis Z" zu schreiben; "X bis Y" reicht völlig aus. Das ist insbesondere dann ratsam, wenn der Ausdruck wiederum mit einer Präposition gebraucht wird, weil zwei Präpositionen nacheinander besonders schlecht wirken. Also nur:

...können die Ergebnisse um 1 bis 14% gesteigert werden.